# Downloading GIS Map for Pakistan into QGIS

Tags: raster, shapefile, data, qgis-2

I'm looking to add canals and bunds to my raster and have found some GIS maps at:

[Canals](http://sida.org.pk/gisweb.aspx?id=2#)

[Bunds](http://sida.org.pk/gisweb.aspx?id=3#)

[Bunds Image](http://sida.org.pk/download/maps/SindhFlood2010.jpg?##)

[Network Plan Map Image - looks to contain both canals and bunds](http://sida.org.pk/download/maps/IrrigationNetworkPlanMap.jpg##)

I'm not clear on how to download or create map or shapefile of these maps. Is there a way to do this in QGIS? Or is there some other way to open the maps on QGIS?

A similar problem at [World map with clear difference between land, sea and inland waterways](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147431/world-map-with-clear-difference-between-land-sea-and-inland-waterways), essentially I am looking to add inland waterways/canals and bunds and just need a good resource for maps containing this I could use in QGIS, if not a way to use the maps I have found.

Comment: It doesn't look like the maps you reference on the Sindh Irrigation and Drainage Authority web site are intended to be downloaded, or used as a web service.  Perhaps you could contact them directly and ask if you could use their data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible in the way you want it. The first two of your Links are Web-Maps integrated into this webpage. You can´t get them this way into Qgis. You might just ask the owners of this page where the data comes from, and if you might use it... Otherwise its just a picture for you to look at.

With the two pictures its nearly the same, but you could if necessary go for georeferencing this images and digitize the elements you need into a shapefile. That would be quite some work with not much accuracy for the data.

Often in such cases its easier to try to get the original data by asking the holders of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can digitize the canals in google earth and convert them to KML file formate. Then you can import the KML file as shape file in QGIS. 
or else you can also digitize the map of Sindh irrigation system using the editor tool, you will get the shape file which you can also edit.